# Исключить ключи из массива - PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Подскажите как удалить синонимы из массива которые меньше 4 символа

```
$string = "Кроме этого, мир людей так же может быть задет от результата великой схватки";

$arr = explode(" ", $string);

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: синонимы к чему? какой результат вы хотите получить для указанной строки?

Comment: Точнее будет слова

Answer (score 1):

Разбить строку по пробелу, отфильтровать полученный массив, и объединить его элементы в строку:

```
$string = "Кроме этого, мир людей так же может быть задет от результата великой схватки";

$string = join(' ', array_filter(explode(" ", $string), function($i){
    return mb_strlen($i) > 3;
}));

echo $string;
```

Результат:

```
Кроме этого, людей может быть задет результата великой схватки
```

Comment: по пробелу разбивать не лучший вариант. возможно, лучше регуляркой по какому нибудь `\b`

Comment: @teran ну да, можно и регуляркой разбить на слова -- если будет нужно, я подкорректирую ответ _(чуть позже, из дома)_

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "Кроме этого, мир людей так же может быть задет от результата великой схватки";

echo preg_replace("/\s?\b\w{1,3}\b/ui", "", $string);
```